# Create post-receive file

Tags: git, config, host

i'm trying to configure my hostgator to use the git.

I has follow this [steps](https://github.com/matthaliski/notes/wiki/Git-push-to-HostGator)

But in my .git/hooks folder, that's no one post-receive.

Just the files:

```
./                      post-update.sample*     prepare-commit-msg.sample*
../                     pre-applypatch.sample*  update.sample*
applypatch-msg.sample*  pre-commit.sample*
commit-msg.sample*      pre-rebase.sample*
```

How Can I create a post-receive file?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there isn't a sample post-receive hook, you can create one just by creating the file `post-receive` inside your `.git/hooks` directory.  You can do that with any text editor, such as `nano` or `vi` (e.g. `nano .git/hooks/post-receive`).

In order for the hook to work, you'd also need to set it executable, which you can do with `chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive`.